# Working with Elasticsearch running on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, kibana, elastic-stack

I've been trying to set up an ELK stack on a low budget. My goal is to familiarize myself with the technology, not to have a heavy-load production-ready system.
Logstash is running on a EC2-micro instance and Elasticsearch on a Raspberry Pi in my local network. Kibana runs on my personal laptop.
With only a few dozen documents indexed, the RPi needs more than 20 seconds to process queries from Kibana. I figured that things would only get worse as the index grows.

I was considering running a replica on my laptop and let ES copy all data whenever I turn it on. The RPi would only stay online to sync with logstash, while data aggregations are performed on my machine. Is that a reasonable approach?

Are there other alternatives to make this work without having to pay for a relatively powerful server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an Intel NUC?

Even a low spec model with the Celeron is considerably faster than the RPI3. It's small and you can get one for less than AUD300. I don't anyone would think of it as a relatively powerful server.

Some performance numbers here: http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linpack%20results.htm